# Most efficient way to count rows of a query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate to retrieve the number of rows for a specific query.  Let's say I have a table called 'Person' with various columns.  One of those columns is 'name'.

If I wanted to get the number of people with the name of 'Andrew', which of these ways would be most efficient?  Assuming there is a performance difference between some/all of them.  Is there a better way to do this using Hibernate/SQL?

(1) Select all columns

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Person where name= :name");
query.setParameter("name", name);
List result = query.list();
int count = result.size();
```

(2) Select just the name column

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select name from Person where name= :name");
query.setParameter("name", name);
List result = query.list();
int count = result.size();
```

(3) Using Count in the query

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select count(*) from Person where name= :name");
query.setParameter("name", name);
long count = (Long) query.uniqueResult();
```

(4) Using Count with the name column in the query

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select count(name) from Person where name= :name");
query.setParameter("name", name);
long count = (Long) query.uniqueResult();
```

Edit: Sorry, I had two number 3's in my list

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: Well right now I'm just writing some experimental code against HSQLDB.  I guess it was more of a general question across all DBs.  Though judging by your question, the answer may differ across DBs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't retrieve a result set if you just want to count the number of rows, this just means useless overhead:

- you'll get more stuff than actually wanted (whether you're selecting all columns or just one)
- you'll need to send them over the wire
- you'll need to create instances (whether it's a full `Person` entity or just a `String`) for nothing.

In other words, if you only want to count, don't do it on the Java side, DBMS are optimized for this task and will do a much better job.

This excludes (1) and (2).

Regarding (3) and (4), note that there is a difference between `count(*)` and `count(col)` in general:

- `count(*)` counts **ALL** rows
- `count(col)` counts rows with **non-null** values of `col`

So they will give different results in performance and query result if `col` can be NULL (the `count(*)` being faster), otherwise identical performance.

I'd use (3).

#### Similar questions

- [COUNT(*) vs. COUNT(1) vs. COUNT(pk): which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better)
- [count(*) vs count(column-name) - which is more correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003457/count-vs-countcolumn-name-which-is-more-correct)
- [Count(*) vs Count(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1)
- [SQL Query: Which one should i use? count(“columnname”), count(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004807/sql-query-which-one-should-i-use-countcolumnname-count1)

Answer (score 0):

The `count(*)` method has profiled to be significantly faster than the `size()` method for my company.  It is certainly more memory efficient since you aren't pulling across column data that you won't use.  I don't know if `count(name)` makes a difference.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, count(*) vs count(name) does make **A LOT** of difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480424/eclipselink-jpa-generates-count-queries-using-countid-instead-count

Answer (score 0):

The less you put inside the `COUNT()` function the better. If you don't need any of the information from the table, I would say use `COUNT(1)`. You can use `COUNT(name)` or `COUNT(*)` as long as your tables are properly indexed.

Comment: The `*` in `COUNT(*)` will not expand into all columns and `count(1)` is equivalent to `count(*)`.

Comment: I would agree, except for in PostgreSQL PL/SQL. At least the last version of PostgreSQL I used there was a difference. In Oracle, MS SQL Server, and MySQL, the two are definitely equivalent. I think it's just a bad habit for me. 

If you're using COUNT() to see if any records exist, for MS SQL the EXISTS() function is more efficient than COUNT().