# Count the number of rows in many to many relationships in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, count, oracle10g

I have three of many tables in Oracle (10g) database as listed below. I'm using Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA with Spring version 3.0.2.

1. **Product** - parent table
2. **Colour** - parent table
3. **ProductColour** - join table - references `colourId` and `prodId` of `Colour` and `Product` tables respectively

Where the `ProductColour` is a *join table* between `Product` and `Colour`. As the table names imply, there is a many-to-many relationship between `Product` and `ProductColour`. I think, the relationship in the database can easily be imagined and is clear with only this much information. Therefore, I'm not going to explore this relationship at length.

One entity (row) in `Product` is associated with any number entities in `Colour` and one entity (row) in `Colour` can also be associated with any number of entities in `Product`.

---

Let's say as for an example, I need to count the number of rows available in the `Product` table (regarding Hibernate), it can be done something like the following.

```
Object rowCount = session.createCriteria(Product.class)
                  .setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
```

---

What if I need to count the number of rows available in the `ProductColour` table? Since, it is a many-to-many relationship, it is mapped in the `Product` and the `Colour` entity classes (POJOs) with there respective `java.util.Set` and no direct POJO class for the `ProductColour` table is available. So the preceding row-counting statement doesn't seem to work in this scenario.

Is there a precise way to count the number of rows of such a **join entity** in Hibernate?

Comment: Already seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3358843/1391249) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do a JPQL or HQL along the lines.

```
SELECT count(p.colors) FROM Product AS p WHERE p.name = :name ... other search criteria etc
```

or

```
SELECT count(c.products) FROM Color AS c WHERE c.name = :name .... other search criteria
```

**From Comment below, this should work:**

```
Long colours=(Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) as cnt from Colour colour where colour.colourId in(select colours.colourId from Product product inner join product.colours colours where product.prodId=:prodId)").setParameter("prodId", prodId).uniqueResult();
```

Comment: I have tried with this HQL `Object o=session.createQuery("select count(p.colours) from Product p where prodId=:prodId").setParameter("prodId", prodId).uniqueResult();` but it unfortunately threw an exception - `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query` where `p.colours` is a valid property in the `Product` entity class. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hi, It worked with this HQL statement - `Long colours=(Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) as cnt from Colour colour where colour.colourId in(select colours.colourId from Product product inner join product.colours colours where product.prodId=:prodId)").setParameter("prodId", prodId).uniqueResult();`. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13388254/1391249) answer. You may now update your answer to reflect as much. Thank you.