# Retrieving rows based on a certain criteria regarding a many-to-many mapping in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, oracle10g, hql

I'm just copy & pasting some of the introductory text from [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13350858/1391249), since the same table relationship is involved in this question also.

---

I have three of many tables in Oracle (10g) database as listed below. I'm using Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA with Spring version 3.0.2.

1. **Product** - parent table
2. **Colour** - parent table
3. **ProductColour** - join table - references `colourId` and `prodId` of `Colour` and `Product` tables respectively

Where the  table `ProductColour` is a *join table* between `Product` and `Colour`. As the table names imply, there is a many-to-many relationship between `Product` and `Colour` which is mapped by `PrductColour`. I think, the relationship in the database can easily be imagined and is clear with only this much information. Therefore, I'm not going to explore this relationship at length unnecessarily.

An entity (row) in `Product` is associated with any number entities in `Colour` and an entity (row) in `Colour` can also be associated with any number of entities in `Product`.

---

Since, it is a many-to-many relationship, it is mapped in the `Product` and the `Colour` entity classes (POJOs) with their respective `java.util.Set` and no direct POJO class for the `product_colour` table is available.

The class `Product` looks like the following.

```
public class Product  implements java.io.Serializable 
{
    private BigDecimal prodId;
    private Set<Colour> colours = new HashSet<Colour>(0);

    .
    .
    .

    //Other properties with setters and getters. 
}
```

The class `Colour` looks like the following.

```
public class Colour implements java.io.Serializable 
{
    private BigDecimal colourId;
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>(0);

    .
    .
    .

    //Other properties with setters and getters. 
}
```

The actual mapping between entities is available in `xxx.hbm.xml` files, regarding this question which is unnecessary, I think .

---

What I want to do is to retrieve only those rows from the `Colour` table which don't match the colour rows in the `ProductColour` table **for a particular product at a time**. In this regard, the native Oracle SQL statement would look something like the following.

```
SELECT colour_id, colour_name, colour_hex
FROM colour
WHERE colour_id not in (SELECT colour_id FROM product_colour WHERE prod_id=81)
ORDER BY colour_id DESC
```

Where `prod_id` can be any valid `BigDecimal` number in Java which is dynamic.

As noted earlier, the relationship is available as a many-to-many relationship in Hibernate, no POJO class for the database table `product_colour` is available and therefore, I'm fumbling in writing such an HQL statement in Hibernate. I have tried to write such an HQL statement but no attempts were succeeded.

---

[The code presented in the rest of the part may completely be unnecessary to review]

I'm therefore following a traditional way. What I'm doing is... I'm first retrieving a single product row from the `Product` the entity class based on a dynamic value of `prodId` such as,

```
List<Product>list=session.createQuery("from Product where prodId=:prodId")
                  .setParameter("prodId", prodId).list();
```

and then using a loop, I'm getting the entire `Colour` set - `java.util.Set` corresponding to the `product_colour` table in Oracle which is available in the `Product` entity for this product such as,

```
Set<Colour>colours=new HashSet<Colour>(0);

for(Product p:list)
{
    if(p!=null)
    {               
        colours=p.getColours();
    }
}
```

As can be seen, the `colours` `Set` is being populated with all of the colour rows available (reference rows) in the `product_colour` table in Oracle.

After getting all of these rows, I'm getting the entire `Colour` entity class itself (all the row in it) that corresponds to the `colour` table in Oracle and then removing those rows which match the rows retrieved from the `product_colour` Oracle table (available in the `colours` Set in the preceding snippet) satisfying the condition as mentioned earlier such as,

```
List<Colour>colourList=session.createQuery("from Colour order by colourId desc").list();
Iterator<Colour>it=colourList.iterator();        

while(it.hasNext())
{
    Colour c=(Colour)it.next();
    for(Colour pc:colours)     //colours is available in the preceding snippet.
    {
        if(c==pc)
        {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

---

This can do what is intended but doing so, may imply some overhead on the system. Additionally, what I want to achieve doesn't seem possible with this approach which is **pagination**. I can't use the `setFirstResult(int)` and the `setMaxResults(int)` methods to accomplish the task of pagination which is the case otherwise like the one shown below regarding the `Product` entity class,

```
List<Product> products=session.createQuery("from product order by prodId desc")
                       .setMaxResults(0).setFirstResult(4);
```

---

**So the question is again**, regarding this relationship, is this possible to write such an HQL statement that can retrieve only those rows from the `Colour` entity class which don't match the colour rows in the `product_colour` Oracle table **like the native SQL statement shown above**?

How can I achieve the concept of pagination otherwise (in case, it is not possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer to a veeeeery long question:

```
select colour from Colour colour 
where colour.id not in (
    select colour2.id from Product product
    inner join product.colours colour2
    where product.id = :productId)
```