# eclipselink jpa generates count queries using COUNT(id) instead COUNT(*)

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Eclipselink, Spring Data and Postgresql. In my project I noticed that when using paged results provided by SpringData repositories there are queries like:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM table 
WHERE [part generated according to specification]
```

where "id" is the primary key of "table". Digging with explain I noticed that COUNT(id) is about 10 times slower than COUNT(*) for a very large table (count(id) looks for non-null values in "id" column while count(* ) simply returns number of rows matching criteria), also count(* ) could make use of indexes while count(id) - not.

I traced the SpringData basic repository class and it seems only JPA implementation is responsible for this query generation.

1. what is the reason of using count(id) instead faster COUNT(* )?
2. can I change this behaviour (anyway - even enhancing existing components)?

any help appreciated

-- [edit] --

there is a table:

```
\d ord_order
                                       Table "public.ord_order"
         Column          |           Type            |                       Modificators
-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 id                      | integer                  | NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('ord_order_id_seq'::regclass)
 test_order              | boolean                  | DEFAULT false
...
Indexes:
    "pk_order" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_test_order" btree (test_order)



# explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ord_order WHERE (test_order = false);
                                QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=89898.79..89898.80 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Index Only Scan using idx_test_order on ord_order  (cost=0.43..85375.37 rows=1809366 width=0)
         Index Cond: (test_order = false)
         Filter: (NOT test_order)
(4 wiersze)



# explain SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ord_order WHERE (test_order = false);
                                QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=712924.52..712924.53 rows=1 width=4)
   ->  Seq Scan on ord_order  (cost=0.00..708401.10 rows=1809366 width=4)
         Filter: (NOT test_order)
(3 wiersze)
```

now the difference is ~90k vs ~713k and index scan vs. full scan

Comment: Please post the execution plans - if `id` is **really** the primary key of the table this is hard to believe. The usual myth is that `count(id)` is faster than `count(*)` so maybe the EclipseLink developers believed that myth (I have never seen it to be  true)

Comment: added query plans in main description. How can count(id) be faster than count(*) while (according to w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) count(*) just returns number of rows matching criteria while count(id) returns number of rows matching criteria AND having non-nul value. It does something additionaly, so it cannot be faster... maybe some specific index could speed it up, but not above the speed of count(*) (at lease I think so)

Comment: How is the column `test_order` defined? And how exactly is the index `idx_test_order` defined?  Does the plan change after running `analyze ord_order`

Comment: test_order is just boolean column with default=false (nulls allowed, but only by schema and there are no nulls in that column), idx_test_order is simple index on this one column (test_order), cannot analyze the table right now. will have to wait for maintenance window.

Comment: I would've expected someone from JPA or Hibernate to comment or provide a solution. This is such a huge bummer, I also recently got hit by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to supply custom Spring Data Repository base class implementation and factory using that implementation. As result generated count queries now have form of:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table
```

which has same plan as COUNT(* ). This seems to be fine solution and works globally for all defined repositories in application.

I did not know how to generate COUNT(* ), COUNT(1) was much easier as COUNT function expects some expressions as parameters and I could supply static value - 1

Answer (score 0):

`count(*)` can use the index because only a single column (`test_order`) is referenced in the query. `count(id)` references two columns and therefor Postgres has to select the `id` column **and** the `test_order` column in order to build the result.

As I have already mentioned, some people think that `count(id)` is faster than `count(*)` - *when there is no restriction on the query*. A myth that has never been true for any DBMS with a decent optimizer. I guess that's why your obfuscation layer is using `count(id)` instead of `count(*)`.

Assuming you don't want to get rid of the ORM (to re-gain control over the SQL that your application is using), the only workaround I can see is to create a partial index that Postgres can use:

```
create index on ord_order (id)
where test_order = false;
```

Comment: that is workaround I already considered and probably follow in short term. The problem is that it is "local" solution - works only for this single table and this single query. As I mentioned queries are built dynamically so conditions may change (the one I placed here is most common one)... I would rather find way to alter QueryBuilder component so that it always uses count(* )...

Comment: OK. tested the index and unfortunatelly it does not work:

create index idx_order_count_opt on ord_order (id) where test_order=false;

# explain SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ord_order WHERE (test_order = false);
 Aggregate  (cost=713178.79..713178.80 rows=1 width=4)
   ->  Seq Scan on ord_order  (cost=0.00..708605.89 rows=1829158 width=4)
         Filter: (NOT test_order)

now - the problem is that MOST of records have test_order=false, so planner does not use index to access values as this wouldn't be any improvement. So I have to work out solution on ORM level.

Comment: @redguy: did you `vacuum analyze` the table after creating the index?

Comment: I did analyze the table and no effect.

Comment: It _should_ use an `Index Only Scan` with that index. What is your exact Postgres version? The index scan in Postgres is unfortunately not as efficient as e.g. in Oracle and sometimes it only uses it after a while (when **all** transactions/sessions using that table are finished).